# Custom repository for "click" packages

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-sdk, click-packages

For standard deb packages we can use reprepro. Is there any custom repository related  solution for "click" packages?

Answer (score 0):

Click packages are the new packaging format used in Ubuntu Touch, and by Ubuntu 14.10, on the desktop version of Ubuntu as well.

Some of the features they provide are:

Simplified packaging for the developer. The Ubuntu SDK can automatically create Click packages of your Ubuntu Touch apps. If you want to create your own, the format is very simple, consisting of two files, `manifest.json` and `<app-name>.json`.

The `manifiest.json` file is the actual package definition and looks like this:

```
{                                                     
    "description": "Your tasks, every device, everywhere. Create and synchronize tasks using Ubuntu One, and connect to your boards in Trello.",
    "framework": "ubuntu-sdk-13.10",
    "hooks": {
        "ubuntu-tasks": {
            "apparmor": "ubuntu-tasks.json",
            "desktop": "ubuntu-tasks.desktop"
        }
    },
    "maintainer": "John Doe <john.doe@gmail.com>",
    "name": "com.ubuntu.developer.johndoe.ubuntu-tasks",
    "title": "Ubuntu Tasks",
    "version": "0.5"
}
```

The `<app.name>.json` file is the security profile for your app and looks like this:

```
{
    "policy_groups": [
        "networking"
    ],
    "policy_version": 1
}
```

To build your package, you can either use the Ubuntu SDK or by running

```
click build
```

The ability to run under confinement. What this means is that the app is prevented from doing bad things. It can only access its own private directory and access features that the user allows the app to use. This means that Click packages are very safe and the review process for publishing them is much simpler.

Once you've packaged your app, you can submit your application to the Click App Store. The review process is very simple and will be completed usually within a few hours. Once reviewed, your app will be available for installation from any device running Ubuntu Touch.

Would they make Debian packaging easier?

Yes and no. Debian packaging is completely different. However, if your app is made with the Ubuntu SDK, you don't need to use Debian packaging and can instead use Click packaging, which is much easier to use and much safer for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one other:

https://open.uappexplorer.com/apps

But basically you can just download and install click packages from wherever.

A click package has only one dependency, the ubuntu framework it was created against.

Whatever extra libs it needs it has to hold them inside the package so there is really no need for repositories that will hold whole hierarchies of packages.